# Javascript: prototypal inheritance and the prototype property

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have a simple code fragment in JS working with prototype inheritance.

```
function object(o) {
    function F() {}
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
}

//the following code block has a alternate version
var mammal = {
    color: "brown",
    getColor: function() {
        return this.color;
    }
}

var myCat = object(mammal);
myCat.meow = function(){return "meow";}
```

that worked fine but adding this:

```
mammal.prototype.kindOf = "predator";
```

does not. (*"mammal.prototype is undefined"*)

Since I guessed that object maybe have no prototype I rewrote it, replacing the var mammal={... block with:

```
function mammal() {
    this.color = "brown";
    this.getColor = function() { return this.color; }
}
```

which gave me a bunch of other errors:

*"Function.prototype.toString called on incompatible object"*
and if I try to call _myCat.getColor()
  *"myCat.getColor is not a function"*

---

Now I am totally confused. After reading Crockford, and Flanagan I did not get the solution for the errors. So it would be great if somebody knows...

- why is the prototype undefined in the first example (which is foremost concern; I thought the prototype of explicitly set in the *object()* function)

- why get I these strange errors trying to use the mammal function as prototype object in the *object()* function?

*Edit by the Creator of the Question:* **These two links helped a lot too:**

[Prototypes_in_JavaScript](http://www.spheredev.org/wiki/Prototypes_in_JavaScript) on the spheredev wiki explains the way the prototype property works relativily simple. What it lacks is some try-out code examples. Some good examples are provided by [Morris John's Article](http://blog.morrisjohns.com/illumination_on_javascript_prototypes.html). I personally find the explanations are not that easy as in the first link, but still very good.
The most difficult part even after I actually got it is really not to confuse the .prototype propery with the internal [[Prototype]] of an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the first error (*mammal.prototype is undefined*) because `mammal` is an object, the [`prototype`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.3.5.2) property is added to function objects when they are [created](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-13.2) and it should be used when you want to have functions as [constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Creating_New_Objects/Using_a_Constructor_Function).

I think you are confusing that property with the internal `[[Prototype]]` property.

The `[[Prototype]]` property can only be set by the `new` operator, through the [`[[Construct]]`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-13.2) internal operation.

This property is not accessible, (although there are some ways, like in the Mozilla implementation by `obj.__proto__;` or the new ECMAScript 5 `Object.getPrototypeOf` method).

About your second question, you get those errors because you are creating a new object, that inherits from a function, not from another object.

What about :

```
var mammal = {
  color: "brown",
  getColor: function(){
    return this.color;
  },
  kindOf: "mammal" // "base" value
};
// ...
var tiger = object(mammal);
tiger.roar = function(){return "roar";}
tiger.kindOf = "predator"; // specific value
```

In the above snippet, all the instances that inherit from `mammal`, will have a `kindOf` property, that you can later change when you create more specific *mammal* objects.

**Edit:** In response to your comment, yes, the language itself gives you the tool to know that, the [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.2.4.5) method, it returns a boolean result, indicating whether the object has physically the specified property or not, e.g.:

```
var obj = {
  foo: 'bar'
};

obj.hasOwnProperty('foo'); // true
obj.hasOwnProperty('toString'); // false, inherited from Object.prototype
```

You can also call this method directly on the `Object.prototype`, so if someone names a property `hasOwnProperty` on an object, it won't fail:

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, 'foo'); // true
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. Prototype still confuses me. Do you know if firebug or any other tool gives a possibility to determine if a method/property is belonging "directly to a object or referred to via a (internal) prototype? It would help me a lot simply trying out for learing.

Comment: Of course, someone could also modify `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`, but if your code is doing stuff like that, all bets are off.